# Please undelete this question on String Theory

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, deleted-questions

For some reason, [Community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1) has deleted my [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65942/23119).

As far as I know, Community only deletes questions upon a certain number (6?) of  "Spam" and "Offensive" flags. What's so spam-like or offensive about that post? Here's the content for those with less than 10k099 rep and non-mods:

> ## Why isn't there a Heterotic string theory which tensors the fermionic state with the Type II state?
>
> The Heterotic (HO and HE) string is found by tensoring the left movers
>   of the bosonic string theory state and the right movers of the Type II
>   string theory state:
>
> $$|ψ_H⟩=|ψ_B⟩⊗|ψ_{II}⟩$$
>
> The bosonic state is of course based on the Polyakov Action. Now, what
>   if we had another state (I'll call it the k-heterotic state) which is
>   formed by tensoring the fermionic string theory state and the type II
>   state.
>
> $$|ψ_H⟩=|ψ_F⟩⊗|ψ_II⟩$$
>
> The fermionic string theory state is based on
>   the Dirac Action:
>
> $$S_F=S_{RNS}−S_B$$ 
>   Why is this theory not consistent?
>   Whether the bosonic state is chosen or the fermionic state, how does
>   that matter? Is it because the Dirac Action is imaginary (since it has
>   an i outside the integral if one expands out the Dirac matrix
>   fermionic field product)? Does it have anything to do with that?

By the way, I wonder if these flaggers were sockpuppets of each other, because I had suddenly started to get 4 downvotes on the mentioned question since  a couple of (20?) days back, which is surprising, because it was initially quite upvoted. So I wonder if the same people had maybe serial flagged this post   and gotten it deleted??? Indicating to me some sort of sockpuppetry...

[image]

Also, these serial downvotes have occured on some others of  my posts, so I hope they don't get deleted too?  Or have they already?

Especially strange (and dangerous), because it doesn't turn up in my [recent deleted questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/23119) either,...

Comment: Hmm, this is strange.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/

Comment: Undeleted for now.

Comment: First time I see a just now on meta when I randomly clicked on the "meta" link !.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it was automatically deleted (cf [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/)).

I have undeleted it, and [also requested that this particular autodelete functionality be turned off for smaller sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198710/should-we-really-have-removedeadquestions-on-smaller-sites)

Comment: By the way, do you know why it was not listed in my deleted recent questions (before it was undeleted, that is)?  http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/23119